# Bigdei Kehuna and the Shechina

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, masechet-yoma, bigdei-kehunah

The Yerushalmi Yoma 2b writes:א"ר תנחום בר יודן ותני לה כל שבעת ימי המילואים היה משה משמש בכהונה גדולה ולא שרתה שכינה על ידיו וכיון שלבש אהרן בגדי כהונה גדולה ושימש שרתה שכינה על ידיו מה טעמא (ויקרא ט) כי היום ה' נראה אליכם

that since Moshe didn't wear the Bigdei kehunah but rather wore a white cloak the Shechina did not rest there (that's how I understood the gemarah). However,since Aron wore the Bigdei Kehuna the Shechina rested there. Didn't Moshe bask in the presence of the Shechina on a daily basis when he went up to Har Sinai.  What changed now that he needed the begdei Kehuna?

Comment: Without seeing the context, could it just mean that the specific *hashra'ath hashechina* associated with the mishkan and all its particular mitzvot, including the *bigdei kehuna*,  was not already present with the *avodoth* that preceded its particular formulas, even though the kohen than was no less than Moshe Rabbeinu himself...

Comment: i.e. it's highlighting the difference in the avodah as prescribed by the Torah from Sinai vs. the avodah from before; and the ability of the kohen gadol who was formulated by the 613 to, as it were, summon G-d's presence, vs. the kohanim gedolim who preceded him, including Moshe.

Comment: You need to define this _Shechina_ concept. Then the answer will be apparent.

Comment: See Rav S R Hirsch (as quoted in [“Terumas Tzvi”](http://www.judaicapress.com/products/the-chumash-trumath-tzvi-with-rabbi-samson-raphael-hirsch-commentary-1-vol)) p 323-4.

Comment: Because Moshe was not a Kohen? And therefore it was inappropriate for him to perform the service set aside for the kohanim? It's... pretty straightforward, actually.